# Intercepting $_GET variable from custom pagination

Tags: pagination, variables

I have a custom pagination using a form with the get action so I can have a page jumper box. Everything works until you enter something that is not an actual page. Examples are negative numbers, text or a number greater than the actual number of pages.

What I am trying to do is intercept the variable and redirect the page if the page doesn't exist.

This is in my functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'k2wp_pagination');
function k2wp_pagination($k2url = '', $pages = '', $range = 2) {

    $showitems = ($range * 2) + 1;

    global $paged;

    if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

    if($pages == '') {
        global $wp_query;
        $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        if(!$pages) {
            $pages = 1;
        }
    }

    if(1 != $pages) {
        echo '<div class="pagination-wrapper clearfix">';
        echo '<form action="' . get_bloginfo('url') .'/'. $k2url . '" class="pagination-buttons" method="get">';
        echo '<div class="pager-buttons btn-group">';
        if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range + 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo '<button value="1" name="paged" class="btn">&laquo; First</button>';
        if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo '<button value="' . ($paged - 1) . '" name="paged" class="btn"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></button>';

        for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
            if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems )) {
            echo ($paged == $i)? '<button value="' . $i . '" name="paged" class="btn disabled" disabled="disabled">' . $i . '</button>' : '<button value="' . $i . '" name="paged" class="btn">' . $i . '</button>';
            }
        }

        if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo '<button value="' . ($paged + 1) . '" name="paged" class="btn"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></button>';  
        if ($paged < $pages-1 && $paged + $range - 1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo '<button value="' . $pages . '" name="paged" class="btn">Last &raquo;</button>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '<form action="' . get_bloginfo('url') .'/'. $k2url . '" class="pagination-jump" method="get">';
        echo '<div class="pager-jump">Page <input alt="Enter page to which you wish to jump" name="paged" type="text" value="' . $paged . '" class="jumper"> of ' . $pages . ' <button class="btn">Go</button></div>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Done.

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you can use $_GET and do all the validation you want to:

- You can look if it's greater than 0
- if it's a string or an integer

  And then use wp_redirect to go the error page or whatever page you want.

Comment: An example would really help.

Comment: Adding an if statement to see if the form has been submitted works but redirecting doesn't work.